# Does Protestant and Christian denominations have stories to tell about bilocation?

Tags: protestantism, miracles

Bilocation is a supernatutal gift of God that is somehow associated to people who had a pious character. Catholic Church  had numerous stories to tell of pious people who later on proclaim as saints. Ven. Mary of Agreda bilocated from one place to another like the now famous St. Padre Pio and many others.

I'm just curious if Protestant Church and Christian denominations also have stories to tell on the pious people that belong to their faith that experience bilocation?

If none, would it mean that there were no pious people that had reach perfection of state like the Catholic Church had produced in their numerous saints that had experienced bilocation?

Comment: "If none, would it mean that there were no pious people that had reach perfection of state like the Catholic Church" Or it would mean that Protestants think bilocation is fictional.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [bilocation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilocation) has a history much beyond the Catholic Church.

Comment: @curiousdanni Can you cite any Protestant pastors who said bilocation of the Catholic Saints are fictional or its just your personal opinion.It would be better if you can provide a link on Protestant stance on this to make your statement credible.

Answer (score 5):

I am unaware of any undisputed evidence of bilocation.  It is not described in the Bible as far as I can tell.  The closest we see are two examples as listed below.

1. Philip in Acts 8:39, 40 where the Spirit "snatched him away) and he appeared suddenly in a different location.
2. The prophet Elijah as mentioned in 1 Kings 18:12.

However, I am not sure that either of these would qualify as bilocation.  Even Jesus, the most perfect and sinless man of all, is never recorded as existing in two places at once (on earth) or even disappearing from one place and suddenly appearing in another place.

For great claims, correspondingly great evidence is required.  There are numerous such fantastic claims about such phenomena but all have a ring of mysticism.

Comment: 'Came Jesus' when the doors were shut, John 20 :19 KJV, implies moving from one location to another (on earth, bodily) by supernatural means but,as you say, does not imply a double, physical existence on earth. (+1).

Comment: Yes,  Jesus had bilocated in the bible in Matthew26:26-28, but since He is God he not only capable of bilocating his body, blood, soul & divinity in two places but in all places where the Host is Consecrated by the priest. The Catholic Church teaches the  Real Presence of Jesua Christ in the Holy Eucharist.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs That's not Protestant teaching, so why do you bring it up?

Comment: @curiousdanni the founder of protestanism Martin Luther believed in the  Real Presence of Jesus body, blood, soul & divinity.And the answer said its not in the bible.Well, it is in the gospel and Book of Acts.How about answering your statement that bilocation is fictional, who are the Protestant thinker's according to your posted commenr, can you name them?

Comment: @itzs Luther and Lutheranism teach something like but not the same as Catholic Transubstantiation. So as I said, why do you keep bringing up Catholic teaching in the comments here? And stop nagging people to write answers.

Comment: @curiousdanii sorry im not nagging im simply asking you to cite who are the  protestant thinkers that said bilocation of catholic saints was fictional,  is that nagging to you?  Regarding M. Luther & Lutheranism were only tallking about "bilocation" and Not "transubstatiation".Protestant having Mass Celebration at the same time at different places is "bilocation" or multilocation of Jesus Christ  body and that is a protestant belief too,  right?

Comment: @itzsophia's vlogs Jesus' body is not said to bilocate during the Protestant sacrament of his death. It is not said to be physically present via the emblems representing him. The Holy Spirit is said to indwell all those who belong to Christ, by faith, as per Romans 8:9-17 but that is not bilocation as in the question. All Christians are called 'saints' in the Bible.

Comment: @Anne read my answer below citing John1:48

Comment: @itzsophia's vlogs Thank you, but Jesus Christ is not just a man "who had a pious character" - the scripture speaks of God incarnate being in one location physically, yet able to see Nathanial who was elsewhere. It does not say Jesus was present i.e. located, under the fig tree otherwise Nathaniel could have seen him. The Holy Spirit enables visions so Jn 1:48 does not prove bilocation of Jesus. Protestants do not support the Catholic idea of bilocation which is what you are asking about. You may believe in it but you are asking what Protestants believe and they don't believe the Catholic idea

Comment: @Anne by your own answer of Christ dwelling in every protestant, if they reach St.Paul perfection in Galatians2:20, then Jesus is bilocating using our own body that become his bodies too, right? So, we become instruments of Jesus bilocation or multilocation as perefect witnessing for Christ image.,right?

Comment: No, there's no qualification of "reaching St. Paul perfection" and Gal 2:20 does not teach that. Nor is this indwelling just for Protestants! All Christians who put faith in Christ are symbolically 'crucified with Christ' at the point of coming to saving faith in Christ, and are indwelt with the Holy Spirit. Paul told all Christians to be confident that 'he who began a good work in you will carry it on to completion until the day of Christ Jesus' Philippians 1:6. The Holy Spirit is Spirit so this bilocation idea cannot apply. Nor have I answered your Q; I've only made comments.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, bilocation does not appear to be restricted to only pious people within the Catholic Church:

> The concept of bilocation has appeared in early Greek philosophy, shamanism, paganism, folklore, occultism, magic, the paranormal, Hinduism (as one of the siddhis), spiritualism, Theosophy, the New Age and mysticism in general, as well as Christian mysticism and Jewish mysticism. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilocation
>
> The claim to this phenomenon is made by many cults and occults, such as pagan witches, spiritualists, shamans, Theosophists, Buddhists, Jewish and Christian mystics, Hindus, and others. (Bible Theology Ministries, U.K., Reformed Christian Doctrine) Source: http://www.christiandoctrine.com/christian-doctrine/heresy-and-error/1295-bilocation

To answer your question, I am unable to find any source that suggests this phenomenon has been experienced by Protestants, regardless of any degree of "piety".

Comment: Thanks for your answer while wikipedia stated the claimed of other people obviously not belonging to Catholic Church as it mentioned paganism, witchcraft, spiritualists of bilocation they are not pious people. My example are the life of known pious people in the Church as their bilocation was attributed to God. The bilocation of witches, spiritualists etc. If its true  does not come from God. Im looking for well known pious christians if there are stories of bilocation over the 500 years of its existence starting in 16th century.

Comment: @Nigel the fuss is all about,  what kind of body does the Saints possessed in order to experience bilocation. Only the Catholic Church had stories of bilocation and incorruption and key is partaking the Holy Eucharist that unfortunately protestant & chritians denominations do not have. In over 500 years Im not sure if there are credible stories of pious christian outside Catholic Church who experienced bilocation.Can you provide a good answer?

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs I can certainly supply an answer. Whether or not it is good, is for the community to judge.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs If deceptive demonic forces are able to cause a person (to seem) to bilocate, and the Bible doesn't list bilocation as a sign for true Christians, I would conclude that these pious people must also have been targeted by the demons. Since God is holy, God would not imitate a practice of the demons from long before Christianity existed.

Comment: @4castle Catholic Church and Protestantism even Martin Luther believe in Jesus bilocation and it is in the bible.It is writen in Matthew & Luke gospel and Book of Acts and St. Paul teaches the real presence of Jesus Christ in the  Holy Eucharist. So, a true christians would not say bilocation is not in the  bible as it will contradict Jesus and St. Paul teachings.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs The case of Jesus is not at all similar to the stories of bilocation told about saints. Jesus was never seen in two locations at once.

Comment: @4castle let me give you an example of Protestant faith. When Mass is celebrated at different places at the same time, protestant by faith believe that it is the body of Jesus Christ himself,  would you not consider that bilocation or multilocation?  Also St. Paul clearly teaches Jesus Christ teaching of Jesus real presence as he reminded in Corinthians not to received the body & blood of Jesus in sacrilege.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs Without going into my personal belief that the bread and wine are just symbols of Jesus' body and blood which were sacrificed once for all time, I would still say that the Protestants who believe that Jesus' body is present during Mass are still not talking about the same thing that is described about saints. Jesus doesn't materialize and interact with peope like the claim is made for these saints. If he did, they would start declaring the second coming.

Comment: @itzsophia's vlogs  Protestants do not believe in transubstantiation. They do not believe that the actual body of Jesus Christ is somehow present during a Catholic mass. Please do not confuse us with Catholicism.

Comment: @Lesley Im not talking of transsubtantiation, im using the Lutheran faith in their own belief that Jesus was present in body & blood in their celebration.And an example of two mass celebration at the same time at different places is also a bilocation, isnt it?

Comment: You said: "When Mass is celebrated at different places at the same time, protestant by faith believe that it is the body of Jesus Christ himself, would you not consider that bilocation or multilocation?" Protestants do not believe that. I know nothing about Lutheran views on the subject. Reformed Protestants do not believe what you just said in your last comment.  I've never heard that view expressed and reject it is a bilocation.

Answer (score 3):

That such stories emanate from the Catholic Church would lead any intelligent person to form an opinion about the Catholic Church, one way or another way.

It is true that, as far as I can find, no valid, Protestant spokesperson has claimed to be able to be in two places (on earth) at the same time.

Nor did any Old Testament prophet. Nor did any Apostle.

Nor was the Lord Jesus, in his humanity, ever recorded to be, though he did say, whilst his own human feet were on the earth :

> ... the Son, of man, which is in heaven ... John 3:13 KJV (plus two commas in context).

To be 'made sit in heavenly (places)' Ephesians 2:6 (KJV and Douay Rheims) is a privilege shared by all persons still on earth, who are true believers in Christ. I am uncertain whether this is classed as 'bilocational'.

If that is accepted as 'bilocational' then I suppose that all true Christians have such a privilege.

Συνεκαθισεν 'made sit together' is in the past tense - strictly speaking, the aorist tense - and so is true now, and is not a matter of the future bodily resurrection. [See Bagster's Analytical Lexicon 'συνεκαθισεν .. third person, singular, aorist 1, indicative'].

And this agrees with the words of the Lord Jesus that, whilst on earth, he was simultaneously in heaven.

For the kingdom of heaven is come among us and those who repent and believe, enter therein, as saith a multitude of scriptures. See [57 verses about Entry into the Kingdom of Heaven.](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Kingdom-Of-God,-Entry-Into)

> Even when we were dead in sins, [the Father of glory (1:17)] hath quickened us together with Christ, (by grace ye are saved;) and hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly places in Christ Jesus. Ephesians 2:6,7 KJV.

Comment: Ephesians2:6-7 speaks of glorification of souls and do not pertain to bilocation. Catholic saints who experienced bilocation are seen in two different places at the same time here on earth and not in Heaven. I think your answer misses the  meaning of bilocation in citing Ehpesians2:6.

Comment: Ephesias2:6 do not speak of two places,  it simply state that sinners are saved by God thru Christ and will be raised together with Christ,  this speaks more of resurrection in the Final Judgement. Did it implied bilocation to you" I hardly can see any clue,  sorry but anyway thanks for the answer .

Comment: The end of John 3:13 as found in the KJV is [not in the oldest manuscripts](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2009727?p=par#h=16)

Comment: @4castle Agreed. Those manuscripts survived because they were little used. The reason they were little used is apparent from their content.

Comment: @4castle read my answer below on Jesus bilocation.John1:48